# Making selection color transparent when in editing mode in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, transparency-opacity

in QGIS, how do I make the selection color transparent?

I need to split a polygon and i want to see the layer underneath it. But I have to select the polygon in order to cut it, and when i do that it turns yellow!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In version 1.7, go to *Preferences* > *Options* > *General* tab (opened by default).
Then, click the yellow color in front of *Selection color* and change the alpha canal value.

My Qgis version is in French, sorry if the translation is not exactly correct.

Comment: Change it to which value?

Comment: vascobnunes > it is set to 255 ... try 20 or 0 to make it fully transparent

Comment: Alpha channel doesn't seem to affect it in the latest build.  Might be a bug, will chase it up.

Comment: @Nathan > Sorry, can't help you. I'm currently working with 1.7. Maybe someone could confirm

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS 2.6:

1. Project Properties:

[image]

2. General, Selection Color:
   [image]
3. Reduce the Opacity:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In QGis 2.2 you need to do the same edit the selection color in "Project Properties" (Win: SHIFT+CTRL+P) to make the selection transparent.

Answer (score 2):

IN 3.18 I tried to change the preference to make the selected item transparent but it doesn't work... but as it turns out, you don't have to select the polygon in order to use the split features tool and cut them.