# How to modifiy how selection highlights are displayed?

Tags: qgis, point, color, select

I have got a layer of points that are showed with a little symbol. When I select one, a red square comes around it. The problem is that these points are inside other layers (polygons) and some of them are red too. I would need to change the color of this square and the width, so that it becomes easily visible.

I could not find anything related to this in the documentation, neither in the asked questions.

I already tried this, but it doesn't affect the red square that remains exactly the same.  My selection colour is setted to Blue under the Project's properties and the square is still red.

And one thing that could be really useful for me, would be to have the width of the square's lines increased.

Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: I forgot to inform that I am using QuantumGIS 1.7.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [When i'm in editing mode in QGIS, how do I make the selection color transparent?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/when-im-in-editing-mode-in-qgis-how-do-i-make-the-selection-color-transparent)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that I fully understand the question, Luis. But you can change the selection colour by going Settings -> Project Properties ... and clicking the "General" tab.

An alternative would be to temporarily remove the fill from the polygons while you work on the points (set the fill style to "No Brush").

Comment: Hello, as I couldn't answer to my own question, I added to answer to you right next to the question.

Comment: @nhopton: I think what Luis want is to change the color and size of those red bounding box of vertices that appear when you enable editing a vector layer and select objects with the Node Tool. If there is no way to do that, your alternative solution above might help!